# Visualising evolution of SOM learning in 2-D

Tags: r, visualization

I am relatively new to data visualisation using R. However, I would like to use R to provide a visual demonstration of how a self-organising map (SOM) learns.

I wondered if someone could help with how to reproduce this types of examples in R, or direct me to reproducible code?

Just even some good pointers would be very help. I can't find anything like this in SOM documentation or R visualisation documentation.

Would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and note which sort of R visualizations you've looked at or tried and why they wouldn't work? Or if you've googled it, what guides have you seen that were in the right direction, but not quite right (and why they didn't fit your needs). If you're an absolute beginner with R, check out the ggplot2 for visualizations as a place to start.

Comment: Hi @Roger-123. Thanks for the feedback. The problem I have is that I have not seen any guidance on how to simulate a singular graph like this (or indeed an evolving set of this type of graph), despite looking in various R texts and libraries (such as ggplot, igraph, etc). So, for sure, if you have seen examples - direction towards them would be helpful. My only source I have found for these types of graphs have been in SOM-based publications where they simulate the SOM learning process. However, unfortunately, they do not often publish their methods.

Comment: For example, I found the example posted above in the following publication: https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1566795.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm(list = ls())
while(!is.null(dev.list()))dev.off()

library(dplyr)
library(kohonen)
library(ggplot2)

nx <- 20; ny <- 20

som.input <- as.matrix(expand.grid(x = seq(-1, 1, length.out = nx), y = seq(-1, 1, length.out = ny))) %>% 
  scale

x.grid <- 10; y.grid <- 10

sgd <- somgrid(x.grid, y.grid,'hexagonal')

som.output <- list()

epoch <- 100

initial.matrix <- matrix(rnorm(x.grid * y.grid * ncol(som.input), 0, .1), nrow = x.grid * y.grid)
training.alpha <- seq(1, .01, length.out = epoch)

som.output[[1]] <- som(som.input, sgd, rlen = 1, init = initial.matrix, alpha = training.alpha[1], mode = 'online')

for(a in 2:epoch) {
  som.output[[a]] <- som(som.input, sgd, rlen = 1, init = som.output[[a-1]]$codes[[1]], alpha = training.alpha[a], mode = 'online')
}

no.picture <- 16

index <- as.integer(seq(1, epoch, length.out = no.picture))

som.codes <- lapply(index, function(input) {
  codes <- som.output[[input]]$codes[[1]] %>% 
    scale(attr(som.input, 'scaled:center'), attr(som.input, 'scaled:scale'))
  
  cbind(
    data.frame(codes * (input / epoch), index = input),
    expand.grid(column = 1:y.grid, rows = 1:x.grid)
  )
})

som.codes <- do.call(rbind, som.codes)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x, y), as.data.frame(som.input), color = 'red', size = 1.1) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y), som.codes, size = 1.9) +
  geom_path(aes(x, y, group = column), as.data.frame(som.codes)) +
  geom_path(aes(x, y, group = rows), as.data.frame(som.codes)) +
  facet_wrap(index ~ .) +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_equal() +
  xlab('') + ylab('')
```

Comment: You're welcome. The point is you have to capture and store each state of the SOM's neurons as opposed to the default behavior of the som() function, which presents only the final result. The process is executed by setting the running length (rlen argument) by a value of 1. The intermediate state of the neuron is then used as input to the next stage of the running process.